# External HDD not mounted error for backup with LuckyBackup

Tags: 14.04, backup, external-hdd

I've come across LuckyBackup to make regular backups on a external drive. I've tried in Ubuntu 12.04 and has run fine saving files to the external hdd.

But when I try ty the same in 14.04 it gives an error message, please see the picture below:

[image]

Well, when I switch the external drive it mounts fine, I can open, explore, read, write in the drive located on /media/meteo/Elements.

Output of mount command

> /dev/sdb1 on /media/meteo/Elements type fuseblk
>   (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)

Anyone having the same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be a stupid question, but does the directory `NUVOL` inside the mounted drive exists? If so, does it have read/write permissions?

Comment: There are not stupid questions but stupid anwers. Yes, it exists and has permissions.

Comment: Mmm the only othe thing I can guess, is if the backup program is running under another user or group that has not permissions to write in it. Someone else may have better clues. Bona sort!

Comment: Hi @darent Found a solution, please see the new post. Thanks for trying to answer. Gràcies!!

Answer (score 2):

Finally found the solution.

It is a known issue with version 0.4.7 (the one in the repos). The author has updated to version 0.4.8 that solves this problem.

You can find the explanation at [this url](http://sourceforge.net/p/luckybackup/discussion/873563/thread/8b8b93db/) and the deb files for 0.4.8 at the [project webpage](http://luckybackup.sourceforge.net/download.html).

Thanks Loukas for a very useful software.